# Javascript - invalid quantifier error, can someone help me see my mistake?

Tags: javascript

I'm not a JS guru, but could someone help me find the invalid quantifier error in the following snippet?

THANKS IN ADVANCE!
-mprototype

```
function $_GET(q,s) {
        s = s ? s : window.location.search;
        var re = new RegExp( '&' + q + '(?:=([^&]*))?(?=&|$)' , 'i' );
        return (s=s.replace(/^?/,'&').match(re)) ? (typeof s[1] == 'undefined' ? '' : decodeURIComponent(s[1])) : undefined;
    }
```

Comment: What is this supposed to do: `/^?/` ? It gives me *SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /^?/: Nothing to repeat*. And maybe you can also explain what the function is supposed to do.

Comment: You need to escape the ?, or strip it from the search string-s = s || window.location.search.substring(1);

Comment: The function is supposed to be used like var var1 = $_GET('key') to use a get var in the javascript

Comment: The funny thing is the function is actually working for using get vars by key identifiers, but I don't like having an error on the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`?` has a special meaning in Regular Expressions, specifically it makes the preceding item optional. If you are trying to find the question mark character itself you need to escape it with a backslash.

```
function $_GET(q,s) {
        s = s ? s : window.location.search;
        var re = new RegExp( '&' + q + '(?:=([^&]*))?(?=&|$)' , 'i' );
        return (s=s.replace(/^\?/,'&').match(re)) ? (typeof s[1] == 'undefined' ? '' : decodeURIComponent(s[1])) : undefined;
    }
```